# Handle long lines while pasting from clipboard without freezing emacs

Tags: clipboard

I have a lengthy xml output from a rest endpoint, I copied if from chrome dev tools to clipboard and on pasting it into an org mode buffer inside an xml source block freezes emacs for a while.

I guess this is because of emacs trying to syntax highlight the xml data.

Pasting the same data with mode changed to fundamental mode works without any issue.

How can I advice emacs to not parse long lines while pasting from clipboard.

Comment: If you could provide an example of a lengthy xml file which produces this problem, probable more people can help.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip

It uses either Emacs internal API or third party CLI tool to insert the text. So syntax highlighting thing is skipped.

You can use simpleclip's default setup. But I recommend re-assign a more convenient key for pasting.

`simpleclip` doesn't work in certain scenario. See https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip/issues/6 for details.

So my current solution combines `simpleclip` and my own code. It covers more scenarios than `simpleclip` (For example, access Windows 10 clipboard inside Linux Subsystem).

Insert below code into `~/.emacs` and run `M-x paste-from-x-clipboard` to paste from clipboard:

```
(unless (featurep 'simpleclip) (require 'simpleclip))
(defun test-simpleclip ()
  (unwind-protect
      (let (retval)
        (condition-case ex
            (progn
              (simpleclip-set-contents "testsimpleclip!")
              (setq retval
                    (string= "testsimpleclip!"
                             (simpleclip-get-contents))))
          ('error
           (message (format "Please install %s to support clipboard from terminal."
                            (cond
                             (or (eq system-type 'gnu/linux)
                                 (eq system-type 'linux)
                                 (eq system-type 'usg-unix-v)
                                 (eq system-type 'berkeley-unix))
                              "xsel")
                             ((or (eq system-type 'cygwin) (eq system-type 'windows-nt))
                              "cygutils-extra from Cygwin")
                             (t
                              "CLI clipboard tools"))))
           (setq retval nil)))
        retval)))
(setq simpleclip-works (test-simpleclip))

(defun my-gclip ()
  (cond
   (simpleclip-works
    (simpleclip-get-contents))
   ((eq system-type 'darwin)
    (with-output-to-string
      (with-current-buffer standard-output
        (call-process "/usr/bin/pbpaste" nil t nil "-Prefer" "txt"))))
   ((eq system-type 'cygwin)
    (with-output-to-string
      (with-current-buffer standard-output
        (call-process "getclip" nil t nil))))
   ((memq system-type '(gnu gnu/linux gnu/kfreebsd))
    (let* ((powershell-program (executable-find "powershell.exe")))
           (cond
            (powershell-program
             ;; PowerLine adds extra white space character at the end of text
             (string-trim-right
              (with-output-to-string
                (with-current-buffer standard-output
                  (call-process powershell-program nil t nil "-command" "Get-Clipboard")))))
            (t
             (with-output-to-string
               (with-current-buffer standard-output
                 (call-process "xsel" nil t nil "--clipboard" "--output")))))))))

(defun paste-from-x-clipboard()
  "Paste from clipboard."
  (interactive "P")
  ;; paste after the cursor in evil normal state
  (when (and (functionp 'evil-normal-state-p)
             (functionp 'evil-move-cursor-back)
             (evil-normal-state-p)
             (not (eolp))
             (not (eobp)))
    (forward-char))
  (insert (my-gclip)))
```

The setup I post here is simplified version. See https://github.com/wangchen/redguardtoo-emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-clipboard.el for my real world setup.

Comment: I was going though the project page and saw this -- https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip/issues/6. I use emacs 25 gui, let me try, ty.